# AngularJS - Form parameters are not passed by submitting form using angular route in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, routes

I am using angularJS routing in PHP application

I have following situation:

I have main page named dashboard.php

and i am opening insertEmployee in ng-View insertEmployee page have form which contains few field. and form tag looks like

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
     <!-- all fields -->

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

When clicked on submit, whole page is reloaded and $_POST['paraName'] shows undefined

I dont want whole page to get reloaded. I want to open the page in ngView with parameters.

There are 8-10 parameters and one of them is employee photo

Answer (score 1):

Remove `action="" method="post"` attributes, you don't want browser to actually send POST request. Instead you subscribe to onsubmit event and handle it yourself:

```
<form ng-submit="save()"> 
    <!-- all fields -->
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.user.username" type="text"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In controller you would implement `save` method and do there whatever needs to be done, e.g. make AJAX POST request, and redirect to another route:

```
function save() {
  // post xhr and redirect
  $http.post('/api/user', this.user)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(user => $location.path(`/user/details/${user.id}`))

  // or better with service
  users.save(this.user)
    .then(user => $location.path(`/user/details/${user.id}`))    
}
```

References:

- ngSubmit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit
- $http.post https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post
- $location https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: I also wants to pass parameters. There are 8-10 parameters

Comment: So pass parameters, you can do it.

Comment: How? I also want to upload image using that form

Comment: Easy! But why are you telling me about file upload only now? I suggest you to update question with *all* the details. How it is now, what I wrote answers it perfectly.